# How to terminate/Kill Sitecore publishing using Sitecore publishing module

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api, publishing-service

We have installed Sitecore publishing module (3.1.1) for Sitecore 9.0.1 version, we have multiple content authors and they are publishing multiple items simultaneously because  of this few of the  authors are need to wait to complete it. We are looking for publish termination pragmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, OOTB There is no such functionality with the `Sitecore publishing service`. The publishing service places all publishing jobs in a queue. When you request a publishing job of any kind, it is queued and then processed as soon as possible. You can see all the active, queued, and completed jobs in the `Publishing Dashboard` application. There is not any OOTB way to clear any of the jobs from the queue but you can directly perform the SQL operations to clear the `Publishing_JobQueue`.

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution I found when you want to reset it forcefully.

If you want to clear the `publishing queue` and making it programmatically,  You need to run the following command from the `Publish Service webroot`:

```
Sitecore.Framework.Publishing.Host schema reset –force
```

The only risk in running this would be if you have any publishing jobs that are in-flight will need to be republished.

You can refer this blog for more details on this.

https://neilkillen.com/2020/11/09/reset-sitecore-publish-service-tables/

And you can also create a program that can run this command as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.